# Mailing an html file

Tags: linux, mutt, html, mail-command

Is it possible to mail an html file that looks exactly like the second image? I know `mutt -e 'set content_type="text/html"' -s "Subject" user@email.com < test.html` works but it sends the html (first image) without the css or "design".

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to send the css file.And If you write your html page with in line css then it won't be a problem.

And if you don't want to use inline css then use this command.

````
mutt -e 'set content_type="text/css"' -s "Subject" user@email.com < test.css```
````

Comment: How can I send the css file also when using mutt if I don’t use inline style?

Comment: `mutt -e 'set content_type="text/css"' -s "Subject" user@email.com < test.css`